# Почему в предложении не ставится запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*Вечером Вадим ушёл в свою комнату и сел перечитывать письмо () и писать ответ.*

Почему мы не ставим запятую перед второй И? Мы же должны ставить запятую перед И при перечислении однородных членов предложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101) (пункт 8):

> Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом *и*, образуют
> тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом *и* с третьим
> однородным членом, запятая не ставится: *Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и
> быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам* (Л. Т.) — парная группа *сбегала и
> сохла* с общим второстепенным членом *по канавам*, оба глагола
> несовершенного вида, в отличие от глагола-сказуемого совершенного вида
> *сбыла*; *Задолго до рассвета Ильинична затопила печь и к утру уже
> выпекла хлеб и насушила две сумы сухарей* (Ш.) — парная группа *выпекла
> и насушила* с общим обстоятельством времени *к утру*; *Любка была девушка
> прямая и бесстрашная и даже по-своему же стойкая в тех случаях, если
> она кого-нибудь не любила* (Ф.); *Фыркает конь и ушами прядёт, брызжет и
> плещет и дале плывёт* (Л); *Первый звук его голоса был слаб и неровен и,
> казалось, не выходил из его груди, но принёсся откуда-то издалек*а
> (Т.); *Пройти огонь и воду и медные трубы* (Погов.); *Он был молод и
> любознателен и считал нужным пользоваться каждым случаем для
> расширения кругозора*.